# Does the Java EE verifier tool still exist?

Tags: jakarta-ee

I was wondering whether the [J2EE verifier](http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Tools11.html) has been updated for recent versions of Java EE or it has been dismissed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Glassfish you can use option "--verify true" for asadmin -deploy

Comment: Thank you, I found some [info for Glassfish 2.1](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19879-01/820-4337/beadq/index.html). I could not find info for Glasshfish 3.1 though.